# What's the meaning of a semicolon inside a while loop?

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand this PHP Snippet

```
public function GetString(){
        $point = $this->bytePointer;
        while($this->GetUInt8() != 0){
            ;
        }

        return substr($this->raw, $point, $this->bytePointer - 1 - $point);
    }
```

what's the meaning of the ";" inside the `while()` loop?

Comment: Probably nothing. Where did you get it from? Maybe it used to have something on that line.

Comment: Technically it should do nothing in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a no-op. The loop has an empty body.

It was possibly included to improve readability. A comment could have made it even more obvious:

```
while (...) {
    // do nothing in the loop body
}
```

You could include any number of semicolons after a statement (which I do not recommend).

All of the following define an empty loop body:

1. ```
   while (...) {
       ;
   }
   ```
2. ```
   while (...) {}  // With any whitespace / newlines within the braces
   ```
3. ```
   while (...); // Note that the semicolon is REQUIRED in case of missing braces!
   ```
4. ```
   while (...) {
       ;;;;;;
       // any number 
       /* and type */
       # of comments 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly used for debugging purpose to stop inside the while to read a value.

Comment: Or to make the `while` a valid statement without the braces at first.